# How to extract the value of textbox (V-Model)?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/KKzLzxg

```
<td><input class="input" v-model="user.name" /></td>
```

If you click the link above, is it possible to extract a specific text value (such as a,b,c)  in the textbox using `.getElementById` or other method? This is a very weird input textbox.

Comment: You might want to include a tag and add to your description that you're using Vue.js (that's the only framework I know that uses the `v-model` attribute) to get better feedback.

Comment: Oh right. Can you show me a codepen demo? Thank you for your attention

Comment: The inputs value would be binded to `user.name`

Comment: can show me a demo pls, thanks?

Comment: just use my existing code and update it

Comment: You shouldn't be using native DOM methods to extract the value from the input. Since you are using `v-model`, the `user.name` is updated dynamically (aka reactive). When do you want to extract the value? Based on a click event initiated by the user? Or how?

Comment: Ok. For example, I want to extract the input text value of the second row. Is it possible to do that maybe with the click of a simple html button?

Answer (score 0):

You have access to the inputs value as the input and `user.name` have a two-way binding through `v-model`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    user: {
      name: ""
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="user.name" /> {{ user.name }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I have a different request. Ok. For example, I want to extract the input text value of the second row. Is it possible to do that maybe with the click of a simple html button?

Comment: The data is there to do what you want with, you'd have to be more specific.